# Generic record/observation log entry management software

Tags: web-apps, database, reporting, statistics

I'm looking for a software that would allow following functionality:

1. Create a record of an observed event (say, an HR-manager files info about an interview with an applicant he's just interviewed). The user must be able to write down an applicant's name, his/her age, qualifications, prior experience, position he/she seeks, that kind of thing. It sounds like your average relational database, but new properties could suddenly appear: suddenly a very skillful but smelly nerd comes around, and the HR-manager decides to leave a note that remote commuting would be best for this one.
2. There are several (up to 50, say) users of the same system. They all use the same database. Each record bears the name of its creator, only the creator or the admin can alter it, but everyone else can read it.
3. The system has to allow creating of custom reports: how many of applicants know C? C++? List of all women just after the first child knowing Ruby. Really complicated statistics, in other words.

To make you less alarmed --- I picked HR-area just for example. I feel that such system ought to be customizable for any domain.

I know that it sounds like your average startup, but the ideas underneath are so basic (gather document records, fulltext-index them, apply queries), that I couldn't help but feel like somebody must've done it already. But the only relevant thing I found is this one: http://www.macropodsoftware.com, and it's a standalone, no server, no authorization.

It doesn't have to be freeware or even opensource. I'm OK with buying it. Any clues?

Comment: One thing to be aware of in the HR scenario is that in several jurisdictions individuals have the right to view and possibly contest or take legal action based on all such computer records about them. UK has this nationally and I believe some or all US states also.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. But the area I intend to apply this software to isn't HR, HR is just an example.

Comment: I am especially aware of this having come across a document full of potentially actionable comments from people regarding job applicants stored in a software departments version control system.  If a friend or relative of any of them were to ever come across it...

Comment: This is all very well and good, but it seems to me that I'll be forced to write this damned piece of code.